# how do you replace a pool pump where PVC installation is coupling to coupling?

Tags: plumbing, pool, pvc

I want to replace my pool pump, and my pool system installers built a system where there is no room for one to make a splice.  There is not one section of pipe exposed greater than 3/4" where I would try to splice cut and extend. It looks to me like I will have to rebuild the entire plumbing section from the ground up, valves and all.

Is there a way to do this and save the valves?  I might have enough on the outlet of the pump, but there is no hope on the suction side.

[image: coupling to coupling pool design]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to cut the pipe. When re-installing you should put in [unions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ALMMRJY) instead of just couplings so that removing the pump is possible without disturbing the system, as the original installers should have.

Since your piping is pretty tight you will need to do some re-piping.

[image]

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Speedy for responding- Unions are a great idea.  but any idea as to where  I can cut? if you look, there is hardly any exposed pipe- it's all connections, and the pipe is contained within...

Comment: @jaytho, I see that. It's hard to say. It will take some creativity. You may need to start at the first connection point on each side. Like at the threaded fitting at the diverter valve and at that black T valve. Hopefully they are threaded and not glue fittings.

Comment: that helps me- the only threaded connections are at the pump and the 5 way valve- so I will unscrew the connections from there, (twist the whole pump body to unscrew) and do something like your system with the unions, but have to move the pump back a little bit.... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

And as to how to save your fittings if you take a socket or something that will fit inside the pipe inside the fitting heat it up stick it in the pipe let it get warm and soft and gooey and then just peel the pipe out you're fittings and Union  be normal not hurt

Comment: You're suggesting that inserting a hot, smaller pipe into the piece of pipe _glued_ into the hub will cause the glue bond to break? Sounds like a great way to end up with the smaller pipe stuck in, since PVC glue softens the PVC and when the solvents evaporate, the two pieces are just as bonded as if they'd been manufactured that way (assuming a good glue joint). Can you find/make a YT video showing this working? I'm rather skeptical.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).